# Joomla - Category Blog Alternative Layout Not Being Applied

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

So I'm a little confused by Joomla's Alternative Layout overrides.

**I'm using Joomla 3.3**

I have read all [Joomla 3.x documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla), and have followed many tutorials without any luck.

So here are my template files:

[image]

Promo is the name of the alternative layout which I would like to activate for one of my Category Pages.

[image]

So it appears as an alternative layout without a problem.

Then I've gone ahead and made the menu item:
[image]

However when I go on the page, it calls the `blog.php` override only and not the `promo.php` layout

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where is your promo.xml file? You should have one in the same directory where you have your promo.php file. The promo.xml file should be a copy of the blog.xml file located under the public_html/components/com_content/views/category/tmpl folder. You will only need to change the line:

```
<layout title="COM_CONTENT_CATEGORY_VIEW_BLOG_TITLE" option="COM_CONTENT_CATEGORY_VIEW_BLOG_OPTION">
```

to

```
<layout title="promo" option="promo">
```

And then when you create a menu item, choose its type to be promo.

Comment: Hi. I have done this and it works for some changes. Changes works on a custom portfolio_item.php that is attached to a menu item. When I click on a sub category link it uses the blog_item.php. Anyone who knows why?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @itoctopus, there are two different things, an alternative layout and an alternate menu layout.  If you make a direct menu link you must use the latter.  For this you need the xml file, and at that point it will show up in your list of menu options.    Alternative layouts are applied to items and the do not show up in the menu options. The menu always overrides the item.  There are some additional options you can play around with.